# How to use Python remote interpreter and its libraries in IntellIj

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose project that uses `python:3.7-slim` image. I have configured this as a remote interpreter. It works great, except that I IntelliJ doesn't see libraries that I've installed inside Docker image (for example, Flask).

How can I configure IntelliJ to respect those libraries?

Comment: If you run a container from command line using this image, do you see those packages?

Comment: Yes, I do. The only way I've found is to run File > Invalidate Cache / Restart. But this takes awful lot of time, I wonder if there is a simpler or faster solution.

Comment: How do you install packages to your docker image? PyCharm manages it through Dockerfile and requirements.txt. Once you add some packages to requirements.txt you should re-build the image. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html

Comment: I do it through bash (inside the container). Rebuilding an image every time I add or remove a dependency seems very over-the-top, especially when I want to test something out. And even if I do rebuild the image, I still have to invalidate cache inside IntelliJ.

Comment: PyCharm removes container when it stops and creates another one based on your image when you run your code again.
So, however inconvenient, your image should have packages installed.
As about the problem that PyCharm cannot find packages even though you rebuilt the image, please report it to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY and attach idea.log from Help | Show Log in...

Comment: Thanks @SergeyK. But even if I create that container using my system terminal and then connect to it with IntelliJ, it will be destroyed _by_ IntelliJ?